# Displaying data from a JSON file with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

As all questions **look** like they are outdatet i'm asking this Question.

First of all I need to mention that I just started Angular 4 days ago, so please explain everything like you would to your child ( or sth. that comes near that haha).

I currently try to retrieve a JSON from a Flask Server.

It has this format.

```
{"id":[1,2,3],"name":["Test 1","Test 2","Test 3"]}
```

The examples will be missing the Imports because it worked properly when testing and now the data should come from a Server.

When I try to Iterate using *ngFor the following error shows up.

```
Error: "Error trying to diff 'Test 1,Test 2,Test 3'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"
```

The HTML for this is:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let test of tests">
          <a routerLink="/detail/{{test.id}}">
          <span>{{test.id}}</span> {{test.name}}
          </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In my test.service.ts it looks the following.

```
...
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

private testUrl = 'http://my.server/tests';

constructor(
  private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

getTests(): Observable<Test[]> {
        return this.http.get<Test[]>(this.testUrl);
        }
...
```

And in my tests.component.ts like this:

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tests',
  templateUrl: './tests.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tests.component.css']
})
export class TestsComponent implements OnInit {
  tests: Test[];

  getTests(): void {
        this.testService.getTests()
                .subscribe(tests => this.tests = tests);

  }


  constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getTests();
  }

}
```

After trying to figure it out for 2 hours I don't know how any further.

If something is missing tell me.

Cheers!

Comment: are you sure that `this.tests` gets array result ?

Comment: because error says `this.tests` gets object  which is  => `{"id":[1,2,3],"name":["Test 1","Test 2","Test 3"]}` and its not an array so you can't bind it to `ngFor`. So you get the error mentioned above.

Comment: Like i mentioned. It should get the JSON, beforehand it recieved an array, after i switched to the Server it doesn't.  The problem could be that it somehow 'screws it up' (which is then my error) but i simply don't know how to handle this. @micronyks do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Its not clear what you want to explain but make sure that `this.tests` must get an array.

Comment: Sorry haha my english is not that good. But well I got a good answer below. Thanks for your help too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the log, the `*ngForOf` is only available for an array.

```
{"id":[1,2,3],"name":["Test 1","Test 2","Test 3"]}
```

You receive this json object(which is not array) and tried to use *ngForOf on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
let test of tests
```

This is the root of your problem. This is not an iterables or array. `tests.id`  and `tests.name` these are arrays. It is very clear by looking at the response from server. `ngFor` will work on `tests.id` or t`ests.name`. `tests` is just an object.

Comment: so you mean i should iterate over tests.id and tests.name got it. But how do i get them so that iterating ovet tests would be possible again? Maybe im just stubborn but knowing more helps more. Thanks for the good answer though :)

Comment: ...so that iterating ovet tests would be possible again? I didn't got your point. Nevertheless, i would suggest you to dig further in your code and if it still dont work , than we will see.

Comment: sometimes very obvious seem too difficult to understand. We just have to give some patience

Comment: Do 2 Things : 1. In your testService.getTests().subscribe(tests => console.log(tests)); Check if you are getting the results as expected or not.

Comment: So just trying it out and corrected it to `let id of tests.id` now i get `
ERROR in src/app/tests/tests.component.html:3:34 - error TS2339: Property Test[]'.

3   <li *ngFor="let id of test.id" >
                                   ~~

  src/app/tests/tests.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './tests.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component TestsComponent.`
 Now im confused.

Comment: 2. Server takes some time to send response. If you are accessing the tests variable before server sends data, than still you will get error.

Comment: console.log doesn't seem to display anything. Mhm. Yes the server could take a while but i can't even build it when i want to add the for loop.

Comment: So im still stuck at `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Test[]'. `